# Git-svn: how to partially merge svn-branch in git

Tags: git, svn, merge

I have a SVN repository that was converted into GIT using git-svn. The structure in SVN master is following:

```
trunk
    A
    B
    C
```

and I have a branch (long-running) in SVN that contains just B and C

```
branches
       refactoring
                 B
                 C
```

Every now and than I have to pick changes from trunk and integrate them into my refactoring branch. Unfortunatelly I didn't find out any better solution as cherry-pick commits from trunk and rebase them onto refactoring branch (this is happaning in GIT).

I looked at the GIT log in Intellij IDEA and it seems to me that those two do not even had any parent.

What I want - I would like to say somehow after I made every cherry: ok, now trunk has been integrated into my refactoring branch and from this time on I would like to merge the changes using rebase or merge but not again with cherry-pick.

Right now if I try to merge trunk into my refactoring branch I get all files from directory A (contains unrelated stuff for refactoring) and many conflicts.

So should I continue to cherry-pick changes from trunk into my branch or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did:

I merged trunk onto our refactoring branch in SVN. We get directory A in git, but that alone saved us many issues.